# How to answer (yes/y) in a CLI prompt? (paramiko remote connection)

Tags: python

How to answer (yes/y) in the CLI prompt after a command is executed? I am using paramiko for command execution.

Below is a piece of my code:

```
try:
    conn2 = ssh.connect(dn_name,
                        username="username",
                        password="password",
                        allow_agent=True,
                        look_for_keys=False
                        )
    if conn2 is None:
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("acidiag touch clean; reload")
        time.sleep(10)
        # Here I need to add a statement for answering YES 
        # to the above command that I gave.
        output = stdout.read()
        print output
        if output:
            ssh.close()
        else:
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("exit")
```

I read about fabric and other modules but I couldn't figure out how to make it work with my piece of code.

Comment: `stdin.write("yes\n")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using `yes` so you don't have to worry about manually saying so:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("acidiag touch clean; yes | reload")
```

Presumably it is the `reload` command specifically that asks for user input. `yes` is a program that outputs `y` repeatedly until killed or its pipe is broken. By piping it into `reload`, it will automatically affirm every prompt.